# Correct Use of XML datatype in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an application that allows my users to make temporary changes to an ongoing booking.  I have recenlty read about the new XML datatype in SQL server, and the corresponding SqlXml type.

I am thinking of using the new type to store the previous values of the object so that I can later revert to them.

Something like:

**Booking Table:**

```
BookingID int
SomeField1 String
SomeField2 String
SomeField3 String
RevertValues XML
RevertDateTime DateTime2
```

This is a cut down version of my table, but I plan to store the current values in the ReverValues column and then revert when the RevertDatetime is reached.

My application uses a SQL Server 2008 database,  Linq-to-SQL model, with a MVC front end.

Any and all advice would be appreciated as I've never done anything like this before!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea to me - I'm doing similar things in SQL Server auditing where I keep audit entries in a table, along with two XML fields - `ValuesBefore` and `ValuesAfter` - to document and track changes.

What you might want to do is split out the "RevertValues" into a separate table that has a foreign key relationship to your bookings, so that you could keep track of several revisions of the booking - something like a `BookingHistory` table:

**BookingHistory**

```
BookingID            INT   (FK to Booking table)
DateOfModification   DATETIME
BookingData          XML
```

or something along those lines.

Marc

Comment: Thanks Marc. How to you store/extract your object in the column?  Serialise/Deserialise methods?  Maybe put xml attributes in my partial class?

Comment: In my case, I simply serialize the object in question to XML and store that. Works fine. I wouldn't store that in your object - but provide a method on the class to render the class contents as XML (return a string)